# Angular with MVC Core catching some routes that should go to controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, angular-routing, angular8, .net-core-2.2

So I am not sure why, but *some* of my routes are making it to my controller, but some are being caught and return the angular stuff.  I will show what I think matters and maybe someone can show what I am missing:

startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "api",
        template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

ThingController.cs:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/thing")]
public class ThingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get/{id:int}")]
    public static Thing Get(int id)
    {
        return new Thing(id);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get-all")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Thing>> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<Thing>();
    }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'things',
    component: ThingsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'thing/:id',
    component: ThingComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/things'
  }
];
```

So, from in my app, I call `localhost/api/thing/get-all` and it hits the controller just fine, but if I call `localhost/api/thing/get/2` I get served the Angular page.  What am I missing that one makes it through and the other doesn't?  Thank you.

Comment: it was was actually because that the 'public static Thing Get' was static (per VS 2019 recommendation)  - changing that fixed it, not totally sure why.

Comment: "When selecting an action, the framework only looks at public **instance** methods on the controller" -- [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection#action-selection)

Static methods are not instance methods.  If the tooling was suggesting to make the method static, it is not paying attention to the needs of the attributes and basing that recommendation on the fact that the method does not reference instance fields or methods (and is therefore presumed viable to be static).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Core 3.0, or if you have migrated your project to Core 3.0, you might want to consider switching to [Endpoint Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code) [Microsoft Docs] like so:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In Core 3.0 it is advised to use `app.UseEndpoints` if possible instead of `app.UseMvc`.

I recently migrated a project from Core 2.2 to Core 3.0.  I found I also needed to make some changes to the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method in `Startup.cs`.  The order you call the features is important:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  ...

  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseCors();

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
  }
```

See the [Routing Starup Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code) section from Microsoft Docs.

Comment: I did just migrate from Core 2 -> 3! I will try this.

Comment: I attempted to add this in, but I am getting IApplicationbuilder does not contain definitions for both UseRouting and UseEndpoints - I have the latest Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc - any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Core did you migrate from?  2.0, 2.1 or 2.2?

Comment: It would seem like not all of the Core 3.0 libraries have updated on your project.  Make sure you make all of the changes in the [Update the project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192222/angular-with-mvc-core-catching-some-routes-that-should-go-to-controllers/58193313?noredirect=1#comment102783105_58193313) instructions

Comment: I was mistaken, I am still on 2.2 - I thought we had updated to 3.0, these extensions are unavailable

Comment: It was because of the `.net-core-3.0` tag that I provided that answer.

Comment: Yes, that was my mess up!

Answer (score 1):

The other change I can suggest is to adjust the `Route Attribute` on your `public static Thing Get(int id)` action.

Try:

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetThing")] //localhost/api/thing/GetThing/2
public static Thing Get(int id)
{
    return new Thing(id);
}
```

Do NOT include the parameter (`{id:int}`) in the Route Attribute.